# Error while Launching saying NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Need help. receiving below error while launching the application

> **Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch**
>   Native stack trace:
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001160421e6 **exceptionPreprocess + 294
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000116fdf031 objc_exception_throw + 48
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000116047472 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
>       3   Foundation                          0x0000000114f7b652 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
>       4   UIKit                               0x0000000112d1bb96 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 3064
>       5   UIKit                               0x00000001130dde4a __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 866
>       6   UIKit                               0x00000001134b0909 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
>       7   UIKit                               0x00000001130dda86 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
>       8   UIKit                               0x00000001130de2a7 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 675
>       9   UIKit                               0x0000000113a4f4d4 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 299
>       10  UIKit                               0x0000000113a4f36e -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
>       11  UIKit                               0x000000011373362d __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221
>       12  UIKit                               0x000000011392e387 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
>       13  UIKit                               0x00000001137334f7 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
>       14  UIKit                               0x00000001134affb0 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
>       15  UIKit                               0x0000000112d19f0c -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515
>       16  UIKit                               0x00000001132eca97 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
>       17  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d9c32f3 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 331
>       18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d9cbcfa __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 225
>       19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000117c74779 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000117c79931 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317
>       21  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d9f7470 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 24
>       22  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d9f712e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 439
>       23  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011d9f768e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
>       24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115fe4bb1 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
>       25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115fc94af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
>       26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115fc8a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
>       27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115fc830b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
>       28  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000119779a73 GSEventRunModal + 62
>       29  UIKit                               0x0000000112d1d0b7 UIApplicationMain + 159
>       30  ???                                 0x000000013437347e 0x0 + 5171000446
>       31  ???                                 0x0000000134373213 0x0 + 5170999827

Comment: The question does not have sufficient information for providing the details.

Answer (score 0):

> **Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application**

It seems that you didn't set the RootViewController.It worked fine in old version.But in the new version ,you should set it in `AppDelegate`

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  // If not required for your application you can safely delete this method

  var indexVC = new XXXViewController ();//your viewcontroller
  Window = new UIWindow ((CGRect)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
  Window .RootViewController = indexVC;
  Window .MakeKeyAndVisible ();

  return true;
}
```